# Google Document or Spreadsheet Add-on being published as Chrome Extention in G Suit and Chrome Webstore

Tags: google-apps-script, chrome-web-store, google-apps-script-addon

I am trying to deploy as Docs add-on and publish the Add-on to both Chrome Webstore as well as G Suit. The problem that I am getting is that when I click on "Preview changes" button before publishing the add-on, I am being redirected to a screen which shows that the add-on is a Chrome Extension. I have not had this problem in the past until recently when I have tried publishing one of my add-ons as unlisted, which got published as Chrome Extension instead of Installable Add-on for Google Documents. I have also got a similar add-on published for Google Sheets, which had some problems but I have managed to fix them and updated the Chrome listing too without any complications. I have emailed Google Add-on advisor, but so far had no response.

I wonder if anyone else has experienced the same problem with publishing Add-ons?

Also, Add-on Curator asked me to post this question here and [Google+ Add-on Developer Community](https://plus.google.com/communities/117193953428311185494)

here is my manifest.json file content:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Add-on Name",
  "version": "1",
  "description": "My Description of the add-on",
  "icons": {
    "128": "icons/add-on_128.png",
    "96": "icons/add-on_96.png",
    "48": "icons/add-on_48.png",
    "32": "icons/add-on_32.png",
    "16": "icons/add-on_16.png"
  },
  "container": ["GOOGLE_DRIVE"],
  "api_console_project_id": "add-on_id",
  "app" : {
    "background": {
      "persistent": false
    }
  },
  "launch" : {
    "web_url" : "example.html"
  }
}
```

Comment: You are using the "old" Developer Dashboard.  There is a new Developer Dashboard that is still in beta.  Have you tried using the new Developer Dashboard?   You need to go to the main window of the current Developer Dashboard and click the link in the notice at the top of the page.  You'll see: "Try out the new Developer Dashboard." at the top.

Comment: Thanks Sandy! I am on the new Developer Dashboard, but it does not change anything and does not help to resolve the problem I am having

Comment: @AlexB What were the steps that you followed to publish your add-on?

Comment: You *must not* generate your own manifest.json content.  The Apps Script code editor  does that automatically.  See [Configure the listing](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/publish-addons#step_5_configure_the_chrome_web_store_listing_and_publish)  See the warning:  Warning: Don't upload a file in the Upload section at the top of the page; Apps Script generates this file automatically for you and uploading a separate file causes the publication to fail.

Comment: @Sandy Good, One that was generated initially also created the same problem for me, The add-on got published as Chrome Extension instead of a Google Docs Add-on

Comment: @Rubén, The steps are, as usual, 1. created the version, 2. Deployed from Manifest, 3. Publish As Docs Add-on, 4. Entered everything into the pop-up dialogue and clicked "Update WebShop Draft", 5. Included images and descriptions then, 6. Preview Changes to see all of the changes. At the last point in the window, it showed that this would be published as Extension and not an add-on.

Comment: You should *not* use the option "Deploy from Manifest."  Use "Deploy as add-on"

Comment: As @Sandy said, you are following the wrong procedure.

Comment: OK, I have deleted the manifest that I have created for it, so now I only have one that was already there "Latest Version (Head) Version 0", I will try to publish only with this one

Comment: Now I get Error, the item is not an app, please remove the app portion from the manifest

Comment: I don't know if you can fix the manifest if the settings are now wrong.  You might need to create a new Apps Script file, and try publishing from a different file.

Comment: Published as a new add-on from the entirely new apps script, no changes published as Extension again

Comment: Again, what are the steps that you are following to publish your add-om?

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE: To publish your add-on, please follow the procedure described on https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/publish-addons

---

AFAIK the old Chrome Web Store Dashboard (CWS) regarding the G Suite Add-ons is in "maintenance mode" from a while, meaning that the Google team have no budget to adapt or improve non-critical/must-have features, specially because they already have a "new Developer Dashboard" and that was announced that the add-ons publishing process will change "soon".

From https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/publish-addons taken on March 9, 2019

> **Warning**: Originally editor add-ons were published to the Chrome Web Store, and could optionally be published in the G Suite Marketplace to make them domain-wide installable.
>
> **Publishing to the G Suite Marketplace is no longer optional**. The publishing instructions below have been revised to reflect this. See [Chrome Web Store migration](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/cws-migration) for more details.

Comment: Hi Ruben, Thank you for your answer. I went through the documentation and followed it to a letter, but the add-on once again got published as Chrome Extension and not a Document add-on. I have updated my question with the manifest.json file that I have uploaded by following the advice here: [Publishing your app](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace/listing?hl=en_GB)